# Rejection reason for "causes harm" too wide with new layout

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits, design

Saw this while in the review queue for a moment:

[image]

The first arrow points to the actual text box being too wide.  The second arrow points to what *appears* to be the text box which is too wide.

Seems that there are some fixed-width `!important` styles in at least one of them which is causing this sort of graphical issue to come up.

Answer (score 4):

This was the same scoping issues as another issue and has been fixed in the next build.

Comment: I'm still observing it. Here on meta too.

Comment: This problem still exists for most people (looking at similar questions)..

Comment: I did observe the issue at least with flagging questions.  It's reproducible on Meta.

Comment: Still get this. Fix ?