# Flag for diamond moderator textarea breaks out of the dialog

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

I noticed the following on the new design:

[image: Oops]

I'm running Chrome Version 39.0.2171.99 (64-bit) on Ubuntu 14.10 x64.

Comment: no repro on same version of Chrome  windows x64

Comment: @Mat probably, although it says [meta-tag:status-complete] and the bug's still there.

Comment: @SecondRikudo [A fix will be rolled out](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/283922/3366929) in the next build.

Comment: @SecondRikudo: I'm not seeing the issue right now on SO.

Comment: On Firefox, it looks different but still broken, the textarea doesn't take the full width of the flag window : http://i.imgur.com/mmQqaIW.png and the number of remaining flags isn't centered.

Comment: I'm still seeing this issue on SO and MSO, even though the "duplicate" bugs have been marked as fixed. The cause seems to be a missing CSS rule (all other sites have the textarea width set to 575px). Voting to reopen.

Comment: I just tried this with chromium 41.0.2272.76 no repro

Comment: This issue was dependent on the OS, browser and installed fonts. On some systems, the text box would be unnecessarily narrow, on others it'd be be too wide. Anyway, looks like [it has finally been fixed properly](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/2467/site-updates-are-live/2479#comment11389_2479).